# Using inner join twice

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, inner-join

Trying to select the Match Table and convert the ID's into the Schools name, but right now I can only get one row to work at a time. What would my select look like instead?

```
select Match.ID, School, GuestTeamID from Match
inner join Team on team.id = match.HomeTeamID
```

Match Table

```
+------------+------------+-------------+
|         ID | HomeTeamID | GuestTeamID |
+------------+------------+-------------+
|          1 |          1 |           2 |
|          2 |          3 |           4 |
+------------+------------+-------------+
```

Team Table:

```
+----+----------+
| ID |  School  |
+----+----------+
|  1 | School A |
|  2 | School B |
|  3 | School C |
|  4 | School D |
+----+----------+
```

Answer (score 4):

Join Team table twice with Match table to fetch school name.

Try this:

```
SELECT M.ID, t1.School AS HomeSchool, t2.School AS GuestSchool
FROM MATCH m 
INNER JOIN Team t1 ON t1.id = m.HomeTeamID
INNER JOIN Team t2 ON t2.id = m.GuestTeamID;
```